# C# Fonet.Standard v1.0.5 multipage issue

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, apache-fop

So I am using stylesheet (for testing) as below with Fonet.Standard v1.0.5 via nuGet. It generates a PDF and when the content of <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body"> is fit for less than a page everything is fine. But when the content makes it overflow only the first page is produced in the PDF, yet the footer correctly indicates that there should be multiple pages i.e. it says Page 1 of 2. The same structure works fine with Apache FOP in a non Windows environment. So should I be doing it a different way with Fonet.Standard? For reference the xml for testing with has been stripped back to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Data>
<DateTime>02/06/2021 10:56</DateTime>
</Data>
```

and the xslt is

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
      xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
      xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
         xmlns:fox="http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/extensions">  
  <fo:layout-master-set>
    <fo:simple-page-master master-name="first" page-height="29.7cm" page-width="21cm" margin-top="18mm" margin-bottom="18mm" margin-left="18mm" margin-right="18mm">
      <fo:region-body margin-top="80mm" margin-bottom="5mm"/>      
      <fo:region-before region-name="header-first"  extent="80mm" />
      <fo:region-after region-name="footer-first" extent="20mm"/>
    </fo:simple-page-master>
    <fo:simple-page-master master-name="rest" page-height="29.7cm" page-width="21cm" margin-top="18mm" margin-bottom="18mm" margin-left="18mm" margin-right="18mm">
      <fo:region-body  margin-top="25mm"  margin-bottom="5mm"/>
      <fo:region-before region-name="header-rest"  extent="25mm" />
      <fo:region-after region-name="footer-rest" extent="5mm"/>
    </fo:simple-page-master>
    <fo:page-sequence-master master-name="document">
      <fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
        <fo:conditional-page-master-reference page-position="first" master-reference="first"/>
        <fo:conditional-page-master-reference page-position="rest" master-reference="rest"/>
      </fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
    </fo:page-sequence-master>
  </fo:layout-master-set>
  <fo:page-sequence master-reference="document">
    <fo:static-content flow-name="footer-first">
      <fo:block padding="1pt" text-align="center">
        page <fo:page-number/> of <fo:page-number-citation ref-id="LastPageIndicator"/>
      </fo:block>      
    </fo:static-content>
    <fo:static-content flow-name="footer-rest">
      <fo:block padding="1pt" text-align="center">
        page <fo:page-number/> of <fo:page-number-citation ref-id="LastPageIndicator"/>
      </fo:block>      
    </fo:static-content>
    <fo:static-content flow-name="header-first">
        <fo:block padding="1pt" text-align="center">
            test first header
        </fo:block>      
    </fo:static-content>
    <fo:static-content flow-name="header-rest">
        <fo:block padding="1pt" text-align="center">
            test rest header
        </fo:block>      
    </fo:static-content>    
    <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
        <fo:block padding="1pt" text-align="center">
test detai here
        </fo:block>      
        <fo:block id="LastPageIndicator"> </fo:block>
    </fo:flow>
    </fo:page-sequence>
    </fo:root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Check the margins, height and with dimensions in the xsd.  They do not look consistent.  I do not know the page sizes you are using for the PDF output so I cannot recommend changes.

Comment: typo in "first" the <fo:region-body should have margin-bottom-"20mm" anything else?

Comment: The page height is 29.7cm which seems small.  The header is 80mm (0.8cm) and the footer 20mm (0.2cm).

Comment: yep 29.7cm is A4 height,  80mm=8cm. 20mm=2cm ... all correct

Comment: Your xslt looks just fine.  Does it help to add the region-name attribute to the fo:region-body like this
<fo:region-body margin-top="80mm" margin-bottom="5mm"  region-name="xsl-region-body"/> ?

Comment: just tried, same, only one page produced with truncated text, footer says page 1of2

Comment: Could please add to your question the result xml that causes the issue. So the xml in "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" namespace, to have more context. Otherwise Or you file an issue for used version of Fonet.Standard?

Comment: have updated with test xml I am now using. I started with rather verbose xml and xslt that was all working when just one page expected. Now that two pages are expected and encountered error I stripped back, and for testing two pages I just replace "test detail here" in the xslt with large static text. When you say file an issue, to where? The nuGet site points to a github project that does not have an issues tab.

Answer (score 1):

sorry ignore the noise! The fonet code works fine. the .Render was using memorystream that later is converted to Pdf and there was code in there from when it was only expected to be a single page. Eventually found when debugged with .Render outputting direct to a file instead of stream.